# How to show custom field's value under post/page title in wp-admin

Tags: custom-field, customization, admin

I'm trying to add the value of a custom field under the post/page title in wp-admin list of posts/pages (much like excerpt mode in posts list) without hooking into the columns process since other plugins are already doing that and it looks like each cancels the other.

Here's a screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: screenshot of pages list]

Thanks!

Comment: Would you settle for adding another column with this data?

Comment: @BrianFegter thanks, but that's something I was able to do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like you add new columns you render the title filed your self

```
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'admin_post_data_row', 10, 2);
function admin_post_data_row($column_name, $post_id)
{
    switch($column_name){
        case 'title':       
            edit_post_link(get_post_title($post_id), '<p>', '</p>',$post_id);
            echo '<br />'.get_post_meta($post_id,'field_name',true);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

and if you have another plugin cancels this then simply set the filter hook priority to something bigger.

Comment: @Amit eyn al maa :)

Answer (score 1):

You can hook into the post_row_actions as follows:

```
add_filter('post_row_actions', 'wpse_43281_post_row_actions', 10, 2);
function wpse_43281_post_row_actions($actions, $post){
    $meta_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'key', true);
    $actions[] = "Meta Value: $meta_value"; //This will add to the hidden hover list
    echo $meta_value; //This will display below the post title 
    return $actions; //Important!
}
```